# help with laplace transform

Tags: laplace-transform

Can you please help me with this Laplace transform? I used wolfram alpha to get the answer but I need some hints about the procedure to get to that answer.

$$
\mathcal{L}\left(\frac {\cos(\sqrt{t})}{\sqrt{t}}\right)
$$

Answer (score 1):

Express the Laplace transform as

$$\begin{align} \underbrace{\int_0^{\infty} dt \frac{\cos{\sqrt{t}}}{\sqrt{t}} e^{-s t}}_{t=u^2} &= 2 \int_0^{\infty} du \, \cos{u} \, e^{-s u^2} \\ &= \Re{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} du \, e^{i u} \, e^{-s u^2}} \\ &= \Re{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} du \, e^{-s [u^2-i(u/s) - 1/(4 s^2)]} e^{-1/(4 s)}} \\ &= e^{-1/(4 s)} \Re{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} du \, e^{-s [u-i/(2 s)]^2}} \\  \end{align}$$

As that last integral is $\sqrt{\pi/s}$, the LT sought is

$$\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{s}} e^{-1/(4 s)}$$

Comment: +1 Do u know there is not and elementary formula in which one can do this L.T.? At least in the well-known books. (-:

Answer (score 0):

HINT

write down the integral and set sqrt(t)=u and use substitution method then use integration by parts twice you will get the answer

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** You can use [Watson's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watson%27s_lemma).

Comment: Mhenni: How can you use Watson's lemma?  It's only useful as an asymptotic approximation in the limit as the transform variable goes to infinity.